# Swift 3 getter method

Tags: ios, properties, swift3, getter

I want to write getter and want that the getter return the same object every time when I call. This is my code.

```
var someObject:NSObject? {
    get {
        if _someObject == nil {
            _someObject = NSObject()
        }
        return _someObject;
    }
}
```

The compiler gives the error
Use of unresolved identifier '_someObject'
How do I write the correct getter method in Swift 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't translate Objective-C code literally.

The Swift equivalent is a lazy computed property

```
lazy var someObject : NSObject = {
    return NSObject()
}()
```

The object is created **once** when the property is accessed the first time and
  you get always a non-optional object.

Comment: Not the same. It means you can't set the variable to nil and have it recalculated automatically - which is a _very_ powerful design pattern.

Comment: @gnasher729 I didn't write it's the same, it's the equivalent to *...return the same object every time when I call*

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, a property named someObject doesn't have a backing variable named _someObject. You *can* of course declare your own private variable named _someObject. As an advantage, there is no need to declare someObject as an optional, since the getter isn't ever supposed to return nil.